# Restructure an array of objects to a deeper level

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I'm trying to create a table using basic HTML (JSX). Each row needs to have a unique date followed by the number of apples, strawberries, bananas and oranges sold on that particular day.

The data I'm receiving from my API makes it difficult to create the table so I need to restructure it.

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    date_sold: "2020-11-14",
    fruit: "Apples",
    amount: 9,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    date_sold: "2020-11-14",
    fruit: "Strawberries",
    amount: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    date_sold: "2020-11-13",
    fruit: "Apples",
    amount: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    date_sold: "2020-11-13",
    fruit: "Oranges",
    amount: 4,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    date_sold: "2020-11-13",
    fruit: "Bananas",
    amount: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    date_sold: "2020-11-13",
    fruit: "Strawberries",
    amount: 3,
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    date_sold: "2020-11-12",
    fruit: "Apples",
    amount: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    date_sold: "2020-11-12",
    fruit: "Bananas",
    amount: 5,
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    date_sold: "2020-11-12",
    fruit: "Strawberries",
    amount: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    date_sold: "2020-11-11",
    fruit: "Apples",
    amount: 8,
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    date_sold: "2020-11-11",
    fruit: "Oranges",
    amount: 3,
  },
];
```

To make it look like this:

```js
const newData = {
  "2020-11-14": { Bananas: 0, Apples: 9, Strawberries: 2, Oranges: 0 },
  "2020-11-13": { Bananas: 2, Apples: 1, Strawberries: 3, Oranges: 4 },
  "2020-11-12": { Bananas: 5, Apples: 2, Strawberries: 2, Oranges: 0 },
  "2020-11-11": { Bananas: 0, Apples: 8, Strawberries: 0, Oranges: 3 },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using `Array.prototype.reduce`.

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    date_sold: "2020-11-14",
    fruit: "Apples",
    amount: 9,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    date_sold: "2020-11-14",
    fruit: "Strawberries",
    amount: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    date_sold: "2020-11-13",
    fruit: "Apples",
    amount: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    date_sold: "2020-11-13",
    fruit: "Oranges",
    amount: 4,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    date_sold: "2020-11-13",
    fruit: "Bananas",
    amount: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    date_sold: "2020-11-13",
    fruit: "Strawberries",
    amount: 3,
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    date_sold: "2020-11-12",
    fruit: "Apples",
    amount: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    date_sold: "2020-11-12",
    fruit: "Bananas",
    amount: 5,
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    date_sold: "2020-11-12",
    fruit: "Strawberries",
    amount: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    date_sold: "2020-11-11",
    fruit: "Apples",
    amount: 8,
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    date_sold: "2020-11-11",
    fruit: "Oranges",
    amount: 3,
  },
];

const output = data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.date_sold] ? acc[cur.date_sold][cur.fruit] = cur.amount : acc[cur.date_sold] = {
    [cur.fruit]: cur.amount
  };
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need create the newData by parts. First, collect all dates and fruits, like:

```js
const dates = [];
const fruits = [];

for (const item of data) {
  if (!dates.includes(data.date_sold))
    dates.push(data.date_sold);
  if (!fruits.includes(data.fruit))
    fruits.push(data.push);
}
```

Then, you can create your newDate object, like:

```js
const newData = Object.fromValues(
  dates.map(function (date) {
    const fruitsCount = Object.fromValues(
      fruits.map(function (fruit) {
        return [fruit, 0];
      })
    });
    for (const item of data) {
      if (item.date === date) {
        fruitsCount[item.fruit] += item.amout;
      }
    }
    return [data, fruitsCount];
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think following solution is more readable.

```
const result = {};

data.forEach(el => {
    const keys = Object.keys(result);
    if (keys.indexOf(el.date_sold) > -1) {
        const amount = result[el.date_sold][el.fruit];
        result[el.date_sold][el.fruit] = (amount || 0) + el.amount;
    } else {
        result[el.date_sold] = {
            [el.fruit]: el.amount
        };
    }
});
```